# Renaming form controls and underlying code

Tags: vba, excel

I was working on adjusting some variable naming on an Excel project and ran into an issue that the MSForm control names needed to be updated. When you change the properties of the control on the form, the underlying code for the form doesn't seem to update accordingly.

Examples:

> 1. You rename `btn_button1` to `btn_populateList`. Now when you click the button it still wants to call `btn_button1_Click()` rather than
>      `btn_populateList_Click()`.
> 2. You rename `inputbox1` to `listToPopulate` but when you run pre-existing code, it still refers to `inputbox1` instead of the new
>      name of the control.

Anyhow, I've always wanted to mess around to get VBA to do stuff in the VBE, so this was my chance!

The macro finds the target project and target form and then updates the control names and appends the string `NEW` to `oldName` such that it's `oldNameNEW`. This was done so I could easily revert the names back using the same procedure with `left(len()-3)`.

Ideally, the array of new names would be populated by the user with descriptive names and would be populated outside of the `For` loop, obviously.

I'm sure there's some clever refactoring that can be done, but I wasn't sure if I'd break it.

Also, I'm worried I misunderstand how Forms call their macros given it's not designed the same way as controls on sheets.

```
Public Sub FindReplaceInEntireModule()
    Const TARGET_ADDIN As String = "bUTLAddIn"
    Const TARGET_FORM As String = "form_chtGrid"

    Dim targetProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim targetModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim targetCode As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim controlIndex As Long
    Set targetProject = Application.VBE.VBProjects(TARGET_ADDIN)

    Set targetModule = targetProject.VBComponents(TARGET_FORM)
    Dim targetForm As Object
    Set targetForm = targetModule.Designer
    Dim numberOfControls As Long
    numberOfControls = targetForm.Controls.count

    Dim newControlNames() As String
    ReDim newControlNames(1 To numberOfControls)
    Dim oldControlNames() As String
    ReDim oldControlNames(1 To numberOfControls)

    For controlIndex = 1 To numberOfControls
        oldControlNames(controlIndex) = targetForm.Controls(controlIndex).name
        newControlNames(controlIndex) = oldControlNames(controlIndex) & "NEW"
        targetForm.Controls(controlIndex).name = newControlNames(controlIndex)
    Next

    Set targetCode = targetModule.CodeModule

    Dim findWhat As String
    Dim replaceWith As String

    Dim numberOfLines As Long
    numberOfLines = targetCode.CountOfLines
    Dim lineNumber As Long
    Dim lineText As String

    For controlIndex = 1 To numberOfControls
        findWhat = oldControlNames(controlIndex)
        replaceWith = newControlNames(controlIndex)
        For lineNumber = 1 To numberOfLines
            lineText = targetCode.Lines(lineNumber, 1)
            If InStr(1, lineText, findWhat, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                targetCode.ReplaceLine lineNumber, Replace(lineText, findWhat, replaceWith, , , vbTextCompare)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Event handlers (be them in forms or elsewhere) are always named `[objectname_eventname]`, so for `Button1.Click` you'll have a handler named `Button1_Click`; if you want to rename the button to `OkButton` you'll need to rename the handler to `OkButton_Click`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've basically implemented (parts of) a *rename* refactoring.

The problem is that the VBIDE API only gives you strings to work with, so you essentially have a "smart find & replace", but it's still a *find & replace*.

A **LOT** of things can go wrong when processing code without a *symbol table*.

Imagine a control named `MyButton` that you want to rename to `SomeButton`. Then you have this code in the module:

```
Dim MyButtonForeColor As Long
MyButtonForeColor = vbBlack
```

Your code will rename `MyButtonForeColor` too, because it contains `MyButton` - but did you *mean* to? In this case, probably.

UserForm controls are `Public`, so you can have code outside the form that does this:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show vbModal
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = .SomeTextBox.Text
End With
```

And that code will break when you rename `SomeTextBox` to anything else.

Or, you could have conflicting but unambiguous names in different scopes, that a simple *find & replace* will break:

```
UserForm1.SomeButton.Caption = UserForm2.SomeButton.Caption
```

Naming is hard. *Renaming* is even harder.

---

Having worked on [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) for over two years, I can assure you that there is absolutely no way to implement any kind of *rename* refactoring without a *symbol table* - and that means *lexing*, *parsing* and *resolving* the VBA code you want to refactor.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> isn't a refactoring tool. Rubberduck is. I don't mean to sound like an ad, but your code needs to know exactly which code *across the entire project* is referencing the control you're renaming - and that simply isn't possible to implement *reliably* in VBA. Heck, Rubberduck *has* a proper parser and resolver, and still struggles with a number of edge cases.

I give you [this code](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/934) to play with - it's EVIL beyond words, I know... but it's 100% legal VBA code, and Rubberduck sorts it all out:

> ```
> 'Project Name = MyProject
> 'Module Name = MyModule
> Option Explicit
>
> Private MyVar As MyProject
> Private MyVar1 As MyModule
>
> Private Type MyProject
>   MyModule As String
>   MySub As String
> End Type
>
> Private Type MyModule
>   MyVar As String
>   String As MyProject
> End Type
>
> Private Type MySub
>   MyVar As MyModule
>   MyVar1 As MyProject
> End Type
>
> Private Type MyVar
>   MyProject As MyModule
> End Type
>
> Sub MySub()
>
>   Dim MyProject As MyProject
>   Dim MySub As MySub
>   Dim MyVar As MyVar
>
>   MyVar.MyProject.MyVar = "Smith"
>   MySub.MyVar1.MySub = MyProject.MySub
>
>   'My brain hurts....
>
> End Sub
> ```

Your strategy (I know you're only looking at controls, but the principle is the same) will fail to correctly rename `MySub` here (whichever you pick).

Your code looks great though - good naming, clean code, nice spacing, indentation, casing, a bit large for a single procedure though, but as I said I don't think any of it is relevant, since there's no way any identifier-renaming VBA macro can work [in all cases] simply by looking at context-less strings.

Comment: ugh. I always do manual find & replace with `Find Whole Word Only` and `Match Case` enabled and *completely* forgot those aren't default.

Comment: @Raystafarian but even *Find whole word only* and *Match case* won't help you deal with mixed scopes.

Comment: Definitely. I meant only in terms of your first point. It's doomed overall regardless. I still had fun writing it though!

Comment: @Raystafarian notice one of the `MyModule` members is named `String`, which is legal for a UDT member. "Doomed" is a correct assessment ;-)

Comment: Dang, who wrote that Evil Code....

Answer (score 3):

**Referring to the current project**

I know you probably meant for this code to be generic so that it works across *any* project, but it would seem that the code is supposed to sit inside your addin.

```
Const TARGET_ADDIN As String = "bUTLAddIn"
Set targetProject = Application.VBE.VBProjects(TARGET_ADDIN)
```

If the name of your add-in changes, you'd need to update the constant, but VBIDE allows you to use:

```
Set targetProject = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
```

**Dim & ReDim**

You can use `ReDim` without using `Dim`, and still get a strongly typed array:

```
ReDim newControlNames(1 To numberOfControls) As String
ReDim oldControlNames(1 To numberOfControls) As String
```

You could also omit the `numberOfControls` variable, and just use the count of the controls.

But you might consider using a 2D array, or maybe a dictionary to keep track of the names.

**Referring to the Form Designer/Controls**

You use `Object` as the type of the Form, when, in this case, it will always actually be a `UserForm`, but you don't actually ever need the form... you need the `Controls`. And the `Controls` are enumerable so you can use 'For..Each`.

```
'Dim targetForm As UserForm 'Early bound type
'Set targetForm = targetModule.Designer
Dim targetControls As Controls
Set targetControls = targetModule.Designer.Controls

ReDim newControlNames(1 To targetControls.Count) As String
ReDim oldControlNames(1 To targetControls.Count) As String

Dim targetControl As Control

For Each targetControl In targetControls
    controlIndex = controlIndex + 1
    oldControlNames(controlIndex) = targetControl.name
    newControlNames(controlIndex) = oldControlNames(controlIndex) & "NEW"
    targetControl.name = newControlNames(controlIndex)
Next targetControl
```

Comment: Thanks for the designer information, I was struggling a bit with that as I've never used the `.designer` property before.